# How to get src of image in androids ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

In my application i need to find out a source of the image in one ImageView so i can put that same image on another ImageView. I need actual source, and not just resource id, because i need to do other actions with it.

I tried with:

`ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
 String  src = view2.getDrawable().toString();`

but I want returned value to be something like:

```
some_packages/image.png
```

same like you get in c# with `image.Source.ToString()`. Is it posible?

Sorry for my english and thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it posible?

Not the way that you are going about it. An `ImageView` does not have to be populated by a resource. It can be using any sort of `Drawable`. A `Drawable` can also be created either in Java code or from a resource. So, neither an `ImageView` nor the `Drawable` inside of it will be able to tell you the resource that is used, as there may not be any such resource.

Either:

- Hold onto the source somewhere else, or
- Put the source in the tag of the `ImageView` [via `setTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and retrieve it later via `getTag()`

Comment: so, if I want to change image multiple times, can I reuse `setTag()` ,or do I somehow need to remove previous tag before putting a new one?

Comment: @barbara: `setTag()`, with the same key, should overwrite the existing value with a new value.